# Validation for mobile : java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX near index 2:

Tags: android, regex

Here I want validation for the mobile number start with `+91` and after `10 digit number`.
I am add the `+91 pincode` into edittext like:

`edtmobile.append("+91(-)");` so when display the edittext(UI) there is already `+91`and after edit 10 digit number

I am using Reg Ex like :

`String regExPhone = "(+91(-)?|91(-)?|0(-)?)?[0-9]{10}";`

but got the error like :

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1411): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX near index 2:
E/AndroidRuntime( 1411): (+91(-)?|91(-)?|0(-)?)?[0-9]{10}
E/AndroidRuntime( 1411):   ^
```

Please let me know where I do mistake, and there is another solutions for same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` is a special character in regex and needs escaping

try

```
String regExPhone = "(\+91(-)?|91(-)?|0(-)?)?[0-9]{10}";
```

you also do not need to group single characters to make them optional, so

```
String regExPhone = "(\+91-?|91-?|0-?)?[0-9]{10}";
```

would be the same.

Comment: `+` is a quantifier (`{1,}`), means it allows to repeat the previous character/group. But because the character before the `+` is a special character itself, it is an error, because it makes no sense to repeat a character with a special meaning.